# Remove RadioButton Icon Android

Tags: android, radio-button

Is there a way to totally remove the Icon from a RadioButton?

I'm bolding the text instead of using the icon.

Setting android:button to either @null or @android:color/transparent
only hides the button and still messes up my test positioning.

I suppose that I could use a dummy view that's only 1dip big, but I wanted to check if there was less of a hack.

Comment: I'm not sure about removing the icon, but you could use a single choice ListView if you don't find a reliable answer.

Comment: Thanks Sam. But I'm not using a ListView. I think that's way overkill. I only have 3 horizontal items.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try setting the background and button to @null.

Comment: sweet. I feel like a dummy. The background is what I was missing. Thanks. Hope I can help you out in the future.

Answer (score 0):

set `android:button="@null"` will remove the default radio icon